# How to install the image_filter module on NGINX Open Source?

Tags: docker, nginx, web, build, nginx-module

I am trying to let nginx handle my static files in my web server. To do that, I want to resize images. I found [ngx_http_image_filter_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html#image_filter) which seems to be what I want. But I can't get it to work.

Ideally, I want a solution for a docker ecosystem. In the official `nginx` image, I think the library is packaged in `/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so` and I heard about the `load_module` line with:

```
load_module "modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";
```

But it does not work with me. I think it is only for nginx Plus users, and I am only using nginx open source, right ?

So, it appears I have to build nginx manually with some arguments, but I can't find a tutorial on how to do that clearly. I tried to tinker with [this Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/hermanbanken/96f0ff298c162a522ddbba44cad31081) but I can't get anything to work.

I already spend a day of work on that issue and it is really frustrating, especially since there seems to be almost no documentation for something I would expect to be a very useful thing. Maybe it is simply not doable with the free nginx ? I am completely lost...

Comment: Do you need to resize the images inside nginx? If you [resize the images first](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-creating-a-image-thumbnails-from-shell-prompt.html) with ImageMagick, you won't have to resize the image on every load.

Comment: Hm ... My idea was that the frontend can request a specific width and height with query parameters for an image. The resizing happens during the request, and only once because of caching. So I need to resize them on every load to do that. Currently, I am using NodeJS and Express to serve the media files with image resizing, but nginx could remove the additional load from the node server

Comment: I thought about letting a node express server do the resizing when needed, creating a new file on the disk, and letting nginx serve the file but I feel like it would be cleaner if nginx was doing the whole process

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, I am sending my work around.

I am using nginx above a NodeJS + express web server. In my solution, the file name is formatted depending on the resizing required, like `abc-123-def_w100_h200.jpg`. If the file is available in the disk, nginx is serving it simply. If it doesn't exist, the request is passed to the node server. There, I test if the original image exists, I modify it using Jimp and I save it on the disk. Then express serves the modified image.

Since the image is not deleted, all the other requests for the modified image with the same parameters will pass through nginx and be much faster. Though, I don't really know how to implement a system similar to caching which would allow me to not saturate the disk of my server...